# Typeahead js Autocomplete no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, autocompletar

Estou implementando o `AUTOCOMPLETE` `typeahead js bootstrap` em minha aplicação Laravel e funciona perfeitamente, atualmente ele retorna somente o nome do município da tabela municípios, só que desta tabela quero que retorne dois valores um do MUNICÍPIO e outro da UF de acordo com que a pessoa digita no campo, não sei como fazer isso pois não entendo muito de `javascript`, fico no aguardo.

***Controller:***

```
public function AutoCompleteCidades(Request $request)
{
    $municipios = Municipio::select("municipio as name", "uf")
                        ->where("municipio","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")->get();
    return response()->json($municipios);
}
```

***View***

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Pesquise</h1>   
    <input class="typeahead form-control" style="margin:0px auto;width:300px;" type="text">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var path = "/autocompletecidades";
   $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
       source:  function (query, process) {
       return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
             return process(data);
       });
     }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: O banco é MySQL? retornar dois valores aonde isso que não ficou muito claro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o banco for [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) utilize a função [concat](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm) da seguinte forma:

***Método:***

```
public function AutoCompleteCidades(Request $request)
{
    $municipios = 
     Municipio::select(DB::raw('concat(municipio, " ",uf) as text, municipio_id as value'))
                ->where("municipio","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
                ->get();
    return response()->json($municipios);
}
```

---

***Html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.4/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
    <style>
        .twitter-typeahead {     
            position: relative;
        }
        .tt-dropdown-menu {
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 160px;
            margin-top: 2px;
            padding: 5px 0;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            *border-right-width: 2px;
            *border-bottom-width: 2px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
            -moz-border-radius: 6px;
            border-radius: 6px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
            -moz-background-clip: padding;
            background-clip: padding-box;
        }
        .tt-suggestion {
            display: block;
            padding: 3px 20px;
        }
        .twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #0081c2;
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0077b3));
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
            background-repeat: repeat-x;
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
        }
        .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor a {
            color: #fff;
        }
        .tt-suggestion p {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>    
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="tid" name="tid" value="" />
    <input class="typeahead form-control" id="ttexto" style="margin:0px auto;width:300px;" type="text">

    <script>        
            $(document).ready(function(){               
                var municipios = new Bloodhound({
                    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("text"),
                    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                    remote: {
                        url: "/autocompletecidades?query=%QUERY",
                        wildcard: '%QUERY'
                    },
                    limit: 10
                });
                municipios.initialize();

                $("#ttexto").typeahead({
                    hint: true,
                    highlight: true,
                    minLength: 1
                },
                {
                    name: "municipios",
                    displayKey: "text",
                    source: municipios.ttAdapter()
                }).bind("typeahead:selected", function(obj, datum, name) {
                    console.log(datum);
                    $(this).data("seletectedId", datum.value);
                    $('#tid').val(datum.value);
                    console.log(datum.value);
                });                        
            });
    </script>  

</body>
</html>
```

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [MySQL - CONCAT Function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamentem mas eu precisaria selecionar o id do municipio  selecionado no value do campo input para mandar o request, como eu poderia fazer isso ? quando eu do um dd($request->all) retorna o nome do municipio ao invés do id: "municipio_id" => "Macapá - AP"

Comment: @BrunoSantos se eu não estiver enganado é um array associativo, então eu fiz uma edição na resposta dá uma olhada lá agora para ver se vai rolar ...

Comment: tentei dessa forma e não carregou o autocomplete.

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada em uma resposta acho que é assim agora faço o teste... @BrunoSantos

Comment: eu vi em um texto que é `label` e `value` que tem que ser informado para Typeahead https://www.upwork.com/hiring/development/creating-autocomplete-functionality-with-php-and-mysql/

Comment: poisé, não to sabendo fazer isso no laravel

Comment: Eu fiz lá na resposta dá uma olhada?

Comment: Não consegui, tentei como está na resposta.

Comment: O que acontece com essa resposta?

Comment: Não está listando os municipios.

Comment: @BrunoSantos eu fiz um código completo e está na resposta editada, o método do `Laravel` mais um página completa com  2 caixas de texto e o código pronto para você utilizar. Seguinte aquele Javascript BootStrap está com `bugs` eu não conseguia fazer ele trabalhar corretamente de jeito nenhum, então eu fui no site e peguei os javascript corretos que estão no exemplo HTML, tem que utilizar eles e o CSS para ficar igual ao Boostrap que também está na resposta, funcionou perfeito agora, precisa ser adaptado ao seu modelo ai... mas, acredito ser fácil com o html. O código javascript é diferente.

Comment: cont ... então tem que ser esse agora para funcionar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60160/discussion-between-bruno-santos-and-virgilio-novic).

Comment: Refiz o teste no Laravel @BrunoSantos funcionou de primeira? ainda está com problemas?

Comment: SIm deu certo agora, muito obrigado!

Comment: Aceita a resposta então... @BrunoSantos